# Use form to log into web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, post

I made a form that sends login data to this website: https://kintai.jinjer.biz/sign_in
I am trying to login to the website using my form.

However when I click submit, the server sends a JSON file as a response.
Is there any way to make the server redirect me to logged in page i.e.  https://kintai.jinjer.biz/staffs/top

Here is my html code for the form

```
    <form method="post" action="https://kintai.jinjer.biz/v1/sign_in" class="login-form"  id="jlogin-form-staff"><dl class="login-form__item">

    <input class="login-input--text jcompanycode" id="company_code" name="company_code"  type="text" value="3809" />

<input class="email login-input--text" name="email" type="text" value="1234" />

<input class="jpassword login-input--text" name="password" placeholder="パスワード" type="password" value="das1728940" />

   <input onclick = "window.location.href= 'https://kintai.jinjer.biz/staffs/top';" type="submit" value= "submit">

</form>
```

I tried using onclick to redirect but it did not work. I also tried using function which did not work.
Any other ideas would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

use [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). add jQuery to your code will make it simpler.

first, change your HTML to this:

```html
<form method="post" action="https://kintai.jinjer.biz/v1/sign_in" class="login-form"  id="jlogin-form-staff">

<dl class="login-form__item">

    <input class="login-input--text jcompanycode" id="company_code" name="company_code"  type="text" value="3809" />

<input class="email login-input--text" name="email" type="text" value="1234" />

<input class="jpassword login-input--text" name="password" placeholder="パスワード" type="password" value="das1728940" />

   <input  type="button" id="submit-form" value= "submit">
</dl>
</form>
```

Then submit the form with ajax.

```js
$("#submit-form").click(function(e) {


    var form = $(".login-form");
    var url = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: form.serialize(), 
           success: function(data)
           {
               window.location.href="https://kintai.jinjer.biz/staffs/top"
           }
         });


});
```

a working example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/c8xds7u4/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. however i still get redirected to the JSON file.  Do you have any other ideas? Kindly help me out

Comment: @Rav edited the answer, added example http://jsfiddle.net/c8xds7u4/

Answer (score -1):

drop the "onclick". the type="submit" is enough for the browser to know when the submit button has been triggered. In addition, made some cosmetic fixes on your code. here:

```
<form method="post" action="https://kintai.jinjer.biz/v1/sign_in" class="login-form"  id="jlogin-form-staff">
    <dl class="login-form__item">

    <input class="login-input--text jcompanycode" id="company_code" name="company_code"  type="text" value="3809" />

    <input class="email login-input--text" name="email" type="text" value="1234" />

    <input class="jpassword login-input--text" name="password" placeholder="パスワード" type="password" value="das1728940" />

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </dl>

</form>
```